# When is --thunder-lock beneficial?

Tags: python, uwsgi

This long, detailed, and entertaining article describes the history and design of `--thunder-lock`: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/SerializingAccept.html

But it doesn't help me decide when I need it!

When is and isn't `--thunder-lock` beneficial?

Answer (score 13):

Well... the answer is not that easy. But in general, you should use it when you're using multiple workers with multiple threads. But...

There are dozens of different operating systems and thunder locking is highly dependent on their capabilities. There are at least six different mechanisms of thunder locking, which are choosed by uWSGI based on operating system capabilities, some of them are better than other. If you're using for example Linux with robust pthread support, you're 99.999999% safe to use thunder-lock.

Comment: Your answer is helpful but also sort of implies "no one can know, unless they do hours of research into the internals of all the software they are using"... surely this isn't how most uwsgi users make their decision :)

Comment: There is a lot of research, when you're trying to make your uWSGI configuration perfect. But basically you can just enable thunder-lock and check what uWSGI is using for that in uWSGI logs. You can even change method manually.

Answer (score 8):

Some performance comparison using very simple and small example is available [here](http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2014-May/007310.html)

It's interesting that as you scale up the number of processes without
the thunderlock for the "hello world" the response time goes
up seemingly linearly as a function of the number of processes I have
spawned. Presumably something checking whether a process is free is
scaling with the number of processes.

The thunder-lock doesn't suffer as badly from that, although there's a
slight performance degradation, although possibly from the OS having
to manage that many processes.